# MYSQL missing days of entries

Tags: mysql5.7

I have a production POS running UBUNTU 16.04 with MYSQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.32, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Today the system lost all records between Jan 04 - Jan 09.

I have various clones of the exact same system and hardware and never had an issue before.

I do not understand how this is possible as every record for this time period no longer exists in the database.
Wondering if anyone can suggest how to debug this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does MySQL log show?

Comment: Did system rebooted, or service restarted?